# How can I construct numpy covariance matrix from database table (load using pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, correlation, covariance

I have a pandas table I read from database and it contains covariance matrix (the number is random so that it is not positive semi-def). I would like a fast way to construct a numpy matrix from the pandas table.

Pandas Table I have

| index1 | index2 | var |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | apple | 1 |
| apple | orange | 1 |
| orange | orange | 0.5 |
| lemon | lemon | 1.2 |
| orange | lemon | -0.5 |
| apple | lemon | -0.8 |

Expected result
`[[1.2, -0.5, -0.8], [-0.5, 0.5, 1.0], [-0.8, 1.0, 1.0]]`

Below is the sample code I tried, but it's not very fast.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd_cov = pd.DataFrame([['apple', 'apple', 1], ['apple', 'orange', 1], ['orange', 'orange', 0.5], ['lemon', 'lemon', 1.2], ['orange', 'lemon', -0.5], ['apple', 'lemon', -0.8]], columns = ['index1', 'index2', 'var'])

def cov_obt(x,y):
    try:
        return(float(pd_cov_ind.loc[x, y]))
    except:
        return(float(pd_cov_ind.loc[y, x]))
ind = list(set(pd_cov['index1']))
pd_cov_ind = pd_cov.set_index(['index1', 'index2'])

np.array([[cov_obt(x,y) for y in ind] for x in ind])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

m = pd_cov.pivot_table(index='index1', columns='index2', 
                       sort=False, fill_value=0).to_numpy()

m = m + m.T - np.tril(m)

m

array([[ 1. ,  1. , -0.8],
       [ 1. ,  0.5, -0.5],
       [-0.8, -0.5,  1.2]])
```

**Explanation**

- Use [`df.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) to pivot your data, with `sort` parameter set to `False` (maintaining order) and `fill_value` set to `0` (needed for step 2). Chain [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) and assign to variable `m`.
- We now have a matrix (`m`) with the upper triangle filled as expected, and the lower triangle still filled with zeros (but for the diagonal). We can "copy" the values from the upper triangle by adding `m` and `m.T` (its transposed version). Since the diagonal will be doubled this way, as a final step, we need to substract the diagonal zeroed, which we can retrieve by applying [`np.tril`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html).